# why are my if statements getting skipped?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, if-statement

So I have a method I call when one of three buttons is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)saveNetwork:(id)sender
{
    NSString *networkEntered;

    if (sender == button1)
        networkEntered = @"button1";

    if (sender == button2)
        networkEntered = @"button2";

    if (sender == button3)
        networkEntered == @"button3";
        //more work...
}
```

the problem is, that it never hits the third if, no matter what is passed in as sender. I've tried else if's, else, etc...

any ideas what's going on?

the problem isn't how I'm passing in the button objects or anything like that because if it is button1 that is pressed, it enters the if just fine, but for some reason it never checks the last one at all.

thanks in advance for the read and the help.

Comment: Lance, now that several hours have passed, don't forget to "Accept" an answer, by clicking on a clear arrow at the left of the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a comparison == in your third if block.  Instead of `networkEntered == @"button3";` you likely want to have `networkEntered = @"button3";`

I expect your third if block is being entered, just not doing what you expect it to.

Comment: Good catch.  The OP should probably try to turn on more compiler warnings.  This sort of problem is usually detected as a "statement has no effect" warning.

Comment: Here is a reference for compiler warnings in XCode - http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/compilercodewarnings.html

Comment: hey thanks :) I discovered that this was the problem a couple hours after I posted this and i had moved on to other problems :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, considering the effect for the third `if` is an equality comparison rather than an assignment, it's no wonder it doesn't work. ;)

```
networkEntered == @"button3";
```

Should be:

```
networkEntered = @"button3";
```

Unless that's just a typo while writing up this question? :)

Answer (score 1):

`networkEntered == @"button3";`
should probably be
`networkEntered = @"button3";`

Answer (score 0):

See if you've hooked up the Touch Up Inside action to the method for the third button.